# php Propel: toArray() method fills in too many objects exponentially larger than intended

Tags: php, schema, propel

I have a fairly straight forward query:
    TableAQuery::create()->leftJoinWith('TableB')->find()->toArray()

The problem is TableB throws back a foriegn reference for all tuples in tableA which have the same reference to tableB.

ie pretend the first 4 of 5 tuples in tableA reference the same tuple in tableB, the result is every tuple in tableB also holds the same 4 references back to tableA:

```
TableA_Array: Array[5]
  0:Object
     id: 0
     tableB_id: 4
     TableB:Object
       id: 4
       TableAs: Object
          TableA_0: "*RECURSION*"
          TableA_1: Object
          TableA_2: Object
          TableA_3: Object
  1:Object
    id: 1
    tableB_id: 4
    TableB:Object
       id: 4
       TableAs: Object
          TableA_0: Object
          TableA_1: "*RECURSION*"
          TableA_2: Object
          TableA_3: Object
  2:Object
     id: 2
     tableB_id: 4
     TableB:Object
       id: 4
       TableAs: Object
          TableA_0: Object
          TableA_1: Object
          TableA_2: "*RECURSION*"
          TableA_3: Object
  3:Object
     id: 3
     tableB_id: 4
     TableB:Object
       id: 4
       TableAs: Object
          TableA_0: Object
          TableA_1: Object
          TableA_2: Object
          TableA_3: "*RECURSION*"
  4:Object
     id: 4
     tableB_id: 77
     TableB:Object
       id: 77
       TableAs: Object
          TableA_0: "*RECURSION*"
```

Here is the schema if you are wondering:

```
<table name="tablea" phpName="TableA">
    <column name="id" type="integer" reqiured="true" primaryKey="true" />
    <column name="tableB_id" type="integer" reqiured="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="tableb">
      <reference local="tableB_id" foreign="id" />
    </foreign-key>
</table>

<table name="tableb" phpName="TableB">
    <column name="id" type="integer" reqiured="true" primaryKey="true" />
</table>
```

In bigger queries the result is an enormous amount of exponential growth that slows down the whole system. How can I avoid the TableA references from TableB, without droping the foreign key reference in the schema?

Comment: I don't know enough about Propel to give a cut answer, but you're probably looking for some form of "lazy-loading" here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `->setFormatter('Propel\Runtime\Formatter\OnDemandFormatter')`

just before `->find()`

and then place `->toArray()` inside your loop

This will only load each object as you need it, not all at once